# Marquee for listview itemtemplate label

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview

How to add a marquee control for **listview** `itemtemplate`?

i use label as itemtemplate.In listview hvae 12 images and 12 labels.

**example:**

```
(If the label text="One" that means
   i don't need marquee 
but 
   the text="This is the sample for marquee in asp.net" above 40 character means 
   i need a marquee)
```

..It is possible.

advance thanks

Comment: Please show us some code or what you tried so far.

Comment: i tried to display hotel menu like image,itemname and price in listview.everything display but itemname should be large means disturbing the website.how to scroll itemname at textoverflow of label.